# Amazon click image based on search

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am very new to selenium and tried this and it didn't work. You can easily reproduce this by going to amazon site and search for hairclip and you will find this image in the search. Once this image is found, i want to go to next page but it is not happening.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\software\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Driver.get("http://www.amazon.com");
    Driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("Hairclip");
    Driver.findElementById("nav-search-submit-button").click();
    
        By by = By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/716AFuiNFoL._AC_UL320_.jpg')]");
    
    
    WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(Driver, 20);
    
    WebElement element = w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
    
    element.click();
```

Error as below

> Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable:
> By.xpath:
> //img[contains(@src,'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/716AFuiNFoL.*AC_UL320*.jpg')]
> (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

I appreciate your time for the reply and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you wanna click on first image, in that case this xpath should work :

```
//img[@data-image-index='1']
```

try it like :

```
WebElement element = w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by.xpath("//img[@data-image-index='1']")));
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPath locator you are using `//img[contains(@src,'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/716AFuiNFoL._AC_UL320_.jpg')]` matches 4 elements on that page.
To click the element you want please use this locator:

```
(//img[contains(@src,'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/716AFuiNFoL._AC_UL320_.jpg')])[last()]
```

So the code line will be

```
By by = By.xpath("(//img[contains(@src,'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/716AFuiNFoL._AC_UL320_.jpg')])[last()]");
```